# Replace one letter in string

Tags: regex, unix, sed

I have some text file on unix:

```
[{"creation_time":"2013-04-18 12:03:33","id":255,"type_id":100,"workflow":167000440},
{"creation_time":"2013-04-18 12:03:33","id":255,"type_id":100,"workflow":167000441}
]
```

I need to write regular expression with SED tool which find the last symbol ] and replace it to ,
so the final rezult would be:

```
[{"creation_time":"2013-04-18 12:03:33","id":255,"type_id":100,"workflow":167000440},
{"creation_time":"2013-04-18 12:03:33","id":255,"type_id":100,"workflow":167000441}
,
```

Thanks in advance.

Uodated.
Thanks all for help, I've checked it and it workes fine, but there could be some situation when tag ] situated in the same line as my expression.

```
[{"creation_time":"2013-04-18 12:03:33","id":255,"type_id":100,"workflow":167000440},
{"creation_time":"2013-04-18 12:03:33","id":255,"type_id":100,"workflow":167000441}]
```

**Copied from comments**

I have write this regular expression but it doesn't work `sed -i '$s/]$//'`

Comment: Is there anything you have done to try to solve this problem? We will be more willing to answer your question if you tell us what you have tried so far. (Helpful links for asking better questions: [ask], [FAQ])

Comment: I have write this regular expression but it doesn't work sed -i '$s/\]$//'

Comment: then maybe you could have put that in your question?

Comment: Why do you need to do it with a regular expression? Why do you need to do it with sed? Are those the only 3 lines in every file or do you have some files with more lines and/or different lines? The better you can describe and show truly REPRESENTATIVE input the better chance you have of getting the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed 's/]$/,/'
```

should make it.

With `$` we indicate end of line.

**Test**

```
$ echo "[{"creati]on_time":"2013-04-18 12:03:33","id":255,"type_id":100,"workflow":167000440},
{"creation_time":"2013-04-18 12:03:33","id":255,"type_id":100,"workflow":167000441}
]" | sed 's/]$/,/'
[{creati]on_time:2013-04-18 12:03:33,id:255,type_id:100,workflow:167000440},
{creation_time:2013-04-18 12:03:33,id:255,type_id:100,workflow:167000441}
,
```

where we can see that if we put other `]` they persist. (In `creati]on_time`)

Answer (score 0):

A safer alternative, depending on your input, would be something like this:

```
sed '/^ *\[/,/\] *$/ { /] *$/ s//,/; }'
```

#### Explanation

Only replace the `]` if it is following a previous `[` and only if it is the last character on the line. Note this will not work if the angle brackets are on the same line.

Comment: @Doorknob: depends on the input, I added some justification.

Comment: @lurii: copy-paste error, the second match/substitute should be in braces.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '$s/]$/,/'
```

This will do the replacement (`s/]$/,/`) on the last line (`$`) only.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
sed -re 's/]$/,/' textfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed ':a ; N ; $\! ba; s/]\([^]]*\)$/,\1/' inputFile
```

this will replace the last '**]**' in the inputFile with '**,**'

Comment: I've got this error:sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unknown command: `\'

Comment: \ was actually put to escape !. Looks like it was not required. Try without \      sed ':a ; N ; $! ba; s/]\([^]]*\)$/,\1/' inputFile